# Copy Activity Not able to copy any response from Rest api in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using input as rest api  url .And I am trying to save the response to a sql table.When I run the pipeline the pipeline run successfully,But it is showing zero rows copied.

I tested the api in postman.I am able to see the reponse data (9 mb)

Anybody else got this same issue,Please help me

Comment: Hi @Being Real, can you provide more information regarding the test API with postman and pipeline snippet?

Comment: no its not poosible actually

Comment: also iam able to copy data to a blob storage

Comment: try mapping of data with sql table.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce and faced similar problem Its not inserting any records.
[image]

The problem is causing due to API returns response in Json and pipeline doesn't know which object value should store in which column.

**To resolve this use `Mapping`. import the scma and amp the paricular columns as below:**

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the intend here is copy the response json to  SQL and if thats the case then we cannot do that with copy activity .
One way is you can use a web activity to call the API and after that you can call a Stored proc activity and pass the response as a input paramter to the SP . The SP will insert the record in the table . But 9MB of response is  too big , i doubt if the web activity can handle that .